# Physical interpretation of Laplace equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Can someone please help me, how from a physical point of view the Laplace equation
$$
\Delta u=0
$$
can be constructed. I want to know some physical applications from where it can be constructed mathematically.

Some explanation or some suitable reference would be fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The potential of an electric field in the absence of any electric charge (density) is a harmonic function -- this easily follows from one of Maxwell's equations ($\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=\cdots$). Also in electromagnetism, the Lorenz gauge is preserved by harmonic functions.

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing here with harmonic functions:

$u$ is called a harmonic function if $\Delta u(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y) \in D$ where $D$ is an open domain of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I am not certain that what I am going to present is answering exactly your question about these functions ; I would like to give you an example issued not from physics but from image processing. This example has helped me to understand the fundamental ["mean value property"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property) of harmonic functions which is :

Whatever $P_0(x_0,y_0) \in D$, the value $u(x_0,y_0)$ is **the mean of the values taken by $u$ on an infinitesimal vicinity of $P_0$**, more precisely on an infinitesimal circle centered in $P_0$. Otherwise said, thinking to the surface with equation $z=u(x,y)$, for a given point $(x,y,z)$ on this kind of circle, having $z \ge u(x_0,y_0)$ is as likely as having $z \le u(x_0,y_0)$.

This property can be given a very natural image by the following discrete analogy. Consider $u$ as a function defined on a square grid with values $u(r,c)$ ($r$ for row, $c$ for column). As the laplacian operator is defined by the sum of the second partial derivatives of $u$ with respect to horizontal and vertical directions:

$$\Delta u:=\partial^2 u/\partial x^2+\partial^2 u/\partial y^2$$

Its classical (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2634843)) approximation is, up to a certain non essential factor here) :

$$\Delta u:=[u(r,c-1)-2 u(r,c)+u(r,c+1)]+[u(r-1,c)-2 u(r,c)+u(r+1,c)]\tag{1}$$

[image]

Let us gather differently the terms of (1):

$$\Delta u:=u(r,c-1)+u(r,c+1)+u(r-1,c)+u(r+1,c)-4 u(r,c)$$

Therefore, constraining $\Delta u=0$ is equivalent to this property:

$$u(r,c)=\dfrac14(u(r,c-1)+u(r,c+1)+u(r-1,c)+u(r+1,c))$$

which means (as said above) that the center value of the cross is the mean of the values taken in its 4 neighbor sites.

Comment: I was forgetting to give an important _physical_ interpretation of the mean value property : it explains that equation $\Delta u=0$ expresses a steady (equilibrium) state for an insulated medium: "I have as many neighbors colder than me than warmer than me".

Answer (score 0):

Laplace started with Newton's law of gravitation, which says that the force with witch a unit mass body is attracted to another body of mass $M$ is proportional to $M$ and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between them. Instead of the force one can consider the following *force potential*:
$$
u=\gamma\,\frac{M}{r}\,,
$$
where
$$
r=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}.
$$
The components of the force field are given by $\nabla u=(u_x,u_y,y_z)$.

If there are several bodies with masses $M_i$ then $u=\sum_i u_i$.

The key idea of Laplace was to consider not the potential $u$ itself but the differential equation it satisfies. I will leave it as an exercise in taking derivatives to find out that for $u_i$ one finds
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u_i}{\partial z^2}=0.
$$
Since $u=\sum_i u_i$ one ends up with
$$
u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}=\Delta u=0,
$$
which is the *Laplace equation*.

*Remark.* It is interesting to note that in most modern textbooks the Laplace equation is motivated by either introducing first Maxwell equation, or diffusion equation, and then consider the *stationary distributions* whereas historically I can say that it was Maxwell who was motivated by Laplace's approach.

*Ref.* Godunov, Equations of mathematical physics, 1979 (I am not sure whether an English translation exists)